# What is the best way to write unicode in python in csv.DictWriter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

I have some data which is in unicode and which I am trying to write into csv file.

I get UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode u'\xa0'...

with the following code

```
import csv
row_all = [u'\n832\xa0\nANDY\n10-04-1987\xa0\nC\n18-02-2015\xa0\nDR\xa0\n2015\xa0\nJS\xa0\nWR\xa0\nAOM/M/BCT\xa0\n\xa0\n90000000\xa0\n'],[u'\n833\xa0\nB V BOND JAMES\n07-04-1962\xa0\nSC\n21-04-1986\xa0\nP\xa0\n2015\xa0\nJAG\xa0\nSCR\xa0\nDY CCM/FS\xa0\n\xa0\n9701370958\xa0\n'],[u'\n834\xa0\nCATHY \n20-02-1983\xa0\nNR\n02-09-2013\xa0\nD\xa0\nNR\xa0\nJS\xa0\nNR\xa0\nAOM/M/MB\xa0\n\xa0\n9760534923\xa0\n'],[u'\n835\xa0\nDAN CLINTON\n31-07-1985\xa0\nCR\n17-12-2012\xa0\nDR\xa0\nNWR\xa0\nJS\xa0\nNWR\xa0\nAOM/C/AII\xa0\n\xa0\n9001196905\xa0\n']

header_row_list = [ "S_No", "NAME" , "Date_of_birth" , "Zone" , "Date_service_joined" , "Recruitment_method" , "Batch" , "Grade" , "Posted_at" , "Designation" , "Telephone_No" , "Mobile"  ]

lst_dx = []
for i in row_all:
    dx_row = {}
    a1 = i[0].split('\n')
    for j in range(1,12+1):
        dx_row[header_row_list[j-1]] = a1[j]
        #dx_row[header_row_list[j-1]] = a1[j].strip()
    lst_dx += [ dx_row ]

g_n = 'test2.csv'
g = open( g_n , 'wb' )
with g as out_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file , fieldnames = header_row_list )
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in lst_dx :
        #writer.writerow([unicode(entry).encode('utf-8') for entry in row])
        writer.writerow(row)
g.close()
```

I can fix this error by using

```
#dx_row[header_row_list[j-1]] = a1[j].strip()
```

But is there a better more "pythonic" way to deal with this and improve this code?

Comment: Encode it as you put it into the `dx_row` dicts, eg ` dx_row[header_row_list[j-1]] = a1[j].encode('utf-8')`. Even better: upgrade to Python 3, where Unicode handling is a lot saner. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Python's `open()` takes an optional keyword argument "encoding".  If you set that to UTF-8, does it do what you're looking for?

Comment: In Python 2 the built-in `open` doesn't take an `encoding` parameter.